# Unhandled Exception Handling

Tags: xamarin.android

In my MonoDroid application, when an unhandled exception occurs the application terminates without any messages. If I can reproduce the error on my local device I can debug it through Visual Studio without any problems.

However, on remote devices I am stuck for a solution.

I have tried the following in the Application class but it does not actually write my log file, unless I am running through the debugger in Visual Studio.

```
public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();                                    
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += new EventHandler<RaiseThrowableEventArgs>(AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser);
    }

    void AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        // Write Log File
    }
```

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the correct one? @SpiritMachine admitted that his answer doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**EDIT :** This code cannot handle caught errors. Please see [@Jim G.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968770/109941)....

Personally, I would localise error handling to where you need it. The reason being, you don't know what your application state will be when this handler is recruited - you may be without resources that you're depending on to do the handling...

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with [@SpiritMachine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354182/109941).

Mono documentation [tells us](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=E:Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser):

> Note: You cannot rely on the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event as managed exceptions are never unhandled in MonoDroid; they are always intercepted at the Android/managed boundary within a catch(Exception) block.

Instead, I recommend that you do the following:

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Do something...
};
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? I believe `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` will also work on Monotouch and WP, making it a cross platform solution.

Comment: Fair enough. It does actually catch the error; you just can't do anything with it - even just logging throws again. I can't delete the answer because it's accepted, but the advice there holds - handle locally.

Comment: "Handle Locally" -- I'm not sure how to interpret that except that every user action (button click, etc) needs its own try/catch. I'm new to Xamarin, but in every other .net situation (web, winform, etc) there's a decent way to at least say, "Something unexpected and bad has happened; here's an exception message and a stack track to give to a developer" (or some such thing). Is there no such mechanism in android/xamarin?

Comment: @pettys: Yes, there is. Follow my advice. Ignore SpiritMachine's. He was just being stubborn.